# Full algorithm (math) of natural cubic splines computation in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, cubic-spline

I'm interested in full Python code (with math formulas) with all computations needed to calculate natural [Cubic Splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines) from scratch. If possible, fast (e.g. Numpy-based).

I created this question only to share my code (as answer) that I programmed recently from scratch (based on Wikipedia) when learning cubic splines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I programmed the following code based on Russian [Wikipedia Article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD), as I see almost the same description and formulas are located in English [Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines).

To speed-up computation I used both [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/).

To check the correctness of code I made tests with comparison to reference implementation of the natural cubic spline of [scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html), you can see `np.allclose(...)` assertion in my code that proves my formulas are correct.

Also, I did timings:

```
calc (spline_scipy): Timed best=2.712 ms, mean=2.792 +- 0.1 ms
calc (spline_numba): Timed best=916.000 us, mean=938.868 +- 17.9 us
speedup: 2.973

use (spline_scipy): Timed best=5.262 ms, mean=5.320 +- 0.1 ms
use (spline_numba): Timed best=4.745 ms, mean=5.420 +- 0.3 ms
speedup: 0.981
```

which shows that my spline-params computation is around `3x` times faster than the Scipy version and usage of spline (computation for given `x`) is the same speed as Scipy.

Running code below needs one-time installing following packages `python -m pip install numpy numba scipy timerit`, here `scipy` and `timerit` are only needed for testing purposes and not needed for actual algorithm.

Code draws plots showing original multi-line and both spline approximation for Scipy and Numba versions, as one can see Scipy and Numba lines are the same (meaning that spline computation is same):

[image]

**Code**:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow67466241#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, numba

# Solves linear system given by Tridiagonal Matrix
# Helper for calculating cubic splines
@numba.njit(
    [f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def tri_diag_solve(A, B, C, F):
    n = B.size
    assert A.ndim == B.ndim == C.ndim == F.ndim == 1 and (
        A.size == B.size == C.size == F.size == n
    ) #, (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape, F.shape)
    Bs, Fs = np.zeros_like(B), np.zeros_like(F)
    Bs[0], Fs[0] = B[0], F[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        Bs[i] = B[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * C[i - 1]
        Fs[i] = F[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * Fs[i - 1]
    x = np.zeros_like(B)
    x[-1] = Fs[-1] / Bs[-1]
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        x[i] = (Fs[i] - C[i] * x[i + 1]) / Bs[i]
    return x
    
# Calculate cubic spline params
@numba.njit(
    #[f'(f{ii}, f{ii}, f{ii}, f{ii})(f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def calc_spline_params(x, y):
    a = y
    h = np.diff(x)
    c = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,), dtype = y.dtype),
        np.append(tri_diag_solve(h[:-1], (h[:-1] + h[1:]) * 2, h[1:],
        ((a[2:] - a[1:-1]) / h[1:] - (a[1:-1] - a[:-2]) / h[:-1]) * 3), 0)))
    d = np.diff(c) / (3 * h)
    b = (a[1:] - a[:-1]) / h + (2 * c[1:] + c[:-1]) / 3 * h
    return a[1:], b, c[1:], d
    
# Spline value calculating function, given params and "x"
@numba.njit(
    [f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], i8[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d):
    dx = x - x0[1:][ix]
    return a[ix] + (b[ix] + (c[ix] + d[ix] * dx) * dx) * dx

@numba.njit(
    [f'i8[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], b1)' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def searchsorted_merge(a, b, sort_b):
    ix = np.zeros((len(b),), dtype = np.int64)
    if sort_b:
        ib = np.argsort(b)
    pa, pb = 0, 0
    while pb < len(b):
        if pa < len(a) and a[pa] < (b[ib[pb]] if sort_b else b[pb]):
            pa += 1
        else:
            ix[pb] = pa
            pb += 1
    return ix
    
# Compute piece-wise spline function for "x" out of sorted "x0" points
@numba.njit([f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def piece_wise_spline(x, x0, a, b, c, d):
    xsh = x.shape
    x = x.ravel()
    #ix = np.searchsorted(x0[1 : -1], x)
    ix = searchsorted_merge(x0[1 : -1], x, False)
    y = func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d)
    y = y.reshape(xsh)
    return y
    
def test():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, scipy.interpolate
    from timerit import Timerit
    Timerit._default_asciimode = True
    np.random.seed(0)
    
    def f(n):
        x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0., n / 5 * np.pi, (n,))).astype(np.float64)
        return x, (np.sin(x) * 5 + np.sin(1 + 2.5 * x) * 3 + np.sin(2 + 0.5 * x) * 2).astype(np.float64)
    def spline_numba(x0, y0):
        a, b, c, d = calc_spline_params(x0, y0)
        return lambda x: piece_wise_spline(x, x0, a, b, c, d)
    def spline_scipy(x0, y0):
        f = scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline(x0, y0, bc_type = 'natural')
        return lambda x: f(x)
    def timings():
        x0, y0 = f(10000)
        s, t = {}, []
        gs = [spline_scipy, spline_numba]
        spline_numba(np.copy(x0[::3]), np.copy(y0[::3])) # pre-compile numba
        for g in gs:
            print('calc (', g.__name__, '): ', sep = '', end = '', flush = True)
            tim = Timerit(num = 150, verbose = 1)
            for _ in tim:
                s_ = g(x0, y0)
            s[g.__name__] = s_
            t.append(tim.mean())
            if len(t) >= 2:
                print('speedup:', round(t[-2] / t[-1], 3))
        print()
        x = np.linspace(x0[0], x0[-1], 50000, dtype = np.float64)
        t = []
        s['spline_numba'](np.copy(x[::3])) # pre-compile numba
        for i in range(len(s)):
            print('use (', gs[i].__name__, '): ', sep = '', end = '', flush = True)
            tim = Timerit(num = 100, verbose = 1)
            sg = s[gs[i].__name__]
            for _ in tim:
                sg(x)
            t.append(tim.mean())
            if len(t) >= 2:
                print('speedup:', round(t[-2] / t[-1], 3))

    x0, y0 = f(50)
    timings()
    shift = 3
    x = np.linspace(x0[0], x0[-1], 1000, dtype = np.float64)
    ys = spline_scipy(x0, y0)(x)
    yn = spline_numba(x0, y0)(x)
    assert np.allclose(ys, yn), np.absolute(ys - yn).max()
    plt.plot(x0, y0, label = 'orig')
    plt.plot(x, ys, label = 'spline_scipy')
    plt.plot(x, yn, '-.', label = 'spline_numba')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```